# Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse) Error : while using pointer inside class

Tags: c++

I'm using visual studio , with this code it gives me an "**Assertion failed**" message .
I have class (C) which have an integer pointer in it with regular set and print methods ,
This is my code :

```
class C
{
    int*   p;
public:
    void print();
    void set_value(int);
    int get_value();
    C();    // default cinstructor
    C(int); //constructor with parameters (overloading constructor)
    ~C();
};

int C::get_value() {
    return *p;
}

void test(C ob1) {
    ob1.print();
}

C::~C()
{
    cout<<p<<" has been destroyed \n";
    if (p!=0)
    delete p;
}

C::C()
{
    p=0;
}

C::C(int x)
{
    p=new int;
    *p=x;
}

void C::print()
{
    if (p!=0)
    cout<<"p = "<<p<<"\t"
        <<"*p = "<<*p<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"Empty pointer"<<endl;
}

void C::set_value(int x)
{
    if (p==0)
        p = new int;
    *p=x;
}
void main()
{
    C x,y(20);
    test(y);
}
```

anyone can help ? thanks in advance .

Comment: It's probably because of memory corruption. You wrote into some memory locations that don't belong to you and this corrupts the internal state of your heap. Where do you get that assert ? What C compiler/environnment do you use ?

Comment: I believe the problem is you have not implemented  a copy constructor and assignment operator for your class: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29 By not implementing these you are getting a double delete when you use your test() function.